# Multiple unnamed namespaces in the same scope?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, namespaces

I'm looking at the pytorch codebase, and I see multiple anonymous namespaces in the same scope like https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/quantized/cpu/qpool.cpp#L23 and https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/quantized/cpu/qpool.cpp#L226

What is the point of this design? Couldn't we just combine them?

Comment: I suppose one could also ask "What is the point of putting multiple definitions in a single anonymous namespace? Couldn't we just put each in its own and let the compiler combine them?" (Point is that there is not always a point to what other people do, and sometimes it's just personal style.)

Answer (score 0):

tldr: multiple unnamed namespaces can help organize related private functions into "groups".

Unnamed namespaces are the modern way of the `static` keyword in old C world. The intention is to make the functions private to that file (compilation unit more strictly).

A typical use case of it is when defining helper functions. Say you have a long function and want to break parts of it into smaller functions. The smaller functions are "implementation details" should not be exposed to the users who include/import your file. You would put them into an unnamed namespace to make them private.

Imagine you have several "public" functions in the file, each of which has its own "private" helper functions. It's more organized to group the private functions, instead of putting all into one huge unnamed namespace.

my 2 cents may not apply to why Pytorch exactly does so though.

Answer (score -1):

> Couldn't we just combine them?

All unnamed namespaces in one parent namespace and within the same translation unit are the same namespace. They can be combined or separated just like named namespaces can be.

> What is the point of this design?

Since I'm not the author of the linked code, I cannot tell why they wrote the program like they did. It could be a design choice, aesthetic preference, an incidental artifact of refactoring or any other reason.

But I can describe an advantage. It is difficult for a human programmer to perceive vertically long scopes (at least without aid of a visualisation tool that an IDE may have). At a glance, when you are in middle of a long file, it's impossible to tell whether you are inside the scope that was started at the beginning of the file or perhaps some other scope. It can be convenient to be able to scroll up only a few lines to find the beginning of the scope. Splitting namespaces into smaller pieces allows that.

This applies to namespaces in general; not only to unnamed namespaces.